# Not expected result when use Linq Select

Tags: c#, linq, select, moq, xunit

I implement unit tests for the engine and setup 2 different methods in the repository mock. So the first one works well, but when I do linq Select for the second one it returns 0, whereas I did setup to return specific object.
My code in Engine:

```
    private readonly IEmployerWorkersClient _employerWorkersClient;
    private readonly IJobsClient _jobsClient;

    public EmployerWorkerEngine(IEmployerWorkersClient employerWorkersClient, IJobsClient jobsClient,)
    {
        _employerWorkersClient = employerWorkersClient;
        _jobsClient = jobsClient;
    }

    public async Task<Grid<WorkerFiltered>> GetWorkersAsync(int employerId, GridState gridState)
    {
        var employerWorkers = await _employerWorkersClient.GetEmployerWorkersByEmployerIdAsync(employerId);

        int? payrollId = null;
        int? jobRoleId = null;
        DateTime? bookedStart = null;

        // !!!the following result is Empty collection!!!
        List<JobRoleExtended> jobRoles = (await _jobsClient.GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync(employerWorkers.Select(ew => ew.Id), payrollId, jobRoleId, bookedStart)).ToList();
        // Other things
    }
```

And hereafter my unit test class

```
    private readonly EmployerWorkerEngine _employerWorkerEngine;

    private readonly Mock<IEmployerWorkersClient> _employerWorkersClientMock;
    private readonly Mock<IJobsClient> _jobClientMock;

    public WorkersFilterTests()
    {
        _employerWorkersClientMock = new Mock<IEmployerWorkersClient>();
        _jobClientMock = new Mock<IJobsClient>();

        _employerWorkerEngine = new EmployerWorkerEngine(_employerWorkersClientMock.Object, _jobClientMock.Object,);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(1)]
    public async Task GetFilteredWorkersByEmployerIdSuccessSimple(int employerId)
    {
        // Arrange
        const int employerWorkerId = 3;
        var gridState = new GridState { Skip = 0, Take = 1 };
        var employerWorkers = new List<EmployerWorker> { new EmployerWorker {EmployerId = 1, WorkerId = 2, Id = employerWorkerId} };

        _employerWorkersClientMock.Setup(client => client.GetEmployerWorkersByEmployerIdAsync(employerId))
            .ReturnsAsync(() => employerWorkers);

        var jobRolesExtended = new List<JobRoleExtended>
        {
            new JobRoleExtended
            {
                EmployerWorkerId = employerWorkerId,
                BookedStartDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                BookedEndDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                Id = 5,
                JobId = 8,
                Name = "Job 5",
                PayrollId = 10,
                PayrollName = "Conduct"
            }
        };

        _jobClientMock
            .Setup(client => client.GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync(employerWorkers.Select(ew => ew.Id), null, null, null))
            .ReturnsAsync(() => jobRolesExtended);
    }
```

So, during testing the following method returns Empty collection:
_jobsClient.GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync() and I don't get why.
I assume that it related with the reference of the collection that generates linq Select, but even in this case, I don't know how to handle it for testing.

Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

does this help:

```
_jobClientMock.Setup(client => client.GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())
        .ReturnsAsync(() => jobRolesExtended);
```

(do check if I got the types right)

if this is the case, then your missing something with your parameters.

Comment: BTW: if you have `var employerWorkers = await _employerWorkersClient.GetEmployerWorkersByEmployerIdAsync(employerId);` why would you do another select in the `client.GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync` with `employerWorkers.Select(ew => ew.Id)`? I assume that your `employerWorkers` are the one with that ID. And does `GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync` expect an array/list or something?

Comment: In the case when I pass It.IsAny<int[]> I won't be able to handle several cases to use different input parameters to extend the unit tests to test different parts.

Comment: I agree, but for the first case, you can see if the list is correctly filled. can you confirm that is the case?

Comment: Yes, sure, It.IsAny is the case, thanks. But I would like to get answer why Select doesn't work in this case and if there is a different reference issue how to handle it?

Comment: My fault, even with IsAny doesn't work properly, returns empty

Comment: Look how it works:
client.GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<int>>(), It.IsAny<int?>(), It.IsAny<int?>(), It.IsAny<DateTime?>())

Comment: do you also have the signature from `GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync` ?

Comment: The signature of that method in my question above

Comment: offcourse I could make an educated guess from `List<JobRoleExtended> jobRoles = (await _jobsClient.GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync(employerWorkers.Select(ew => ew.Id), payrollId, jobRoleId, bookedStart)).ToList();`, just wanted to make sure that the Interface is the same..

Answer (score 1):

With Moq you have to setup the expectations correctly or else when called the mock wont match and thus not perform as expected.

In the method under test you have

```
int? payrollId = null;
int? jobRoleId = null;
DateTime? bookedStart = null;

List<JobRoleExtended> jobRoles = 
    (await _jobsClient.GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync(
        employerWorkers.Select(ew => ew.Id), payrollId, jobRoleId, bookedStart)
    )
    .ToList();
```

The `Select` statement appears to be returning a collection of Ids (`IEnumerable<int>`) and you have already configured the first call correctly.

You now need to correctly configure the second call to expect that collection of int Ids

```
_jobClientMock
    .Setup(_ => _.GetJobRoleExtendedByEmployerWorkerIdsAsync(
                    It.IsAny<IEnumerable<int>>(), 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null)
    )
    .ReturnsAsync(() => jobRolesExtended);
```